# React How to Print a PDF File Within a Component View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'd like to learn how I can print a PDF doc rendered inside a React Component. Currently, my event handler isn't firing accordingly to enable printing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const pdfFile =
  "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";

export default class PDFViewer extends Component {
  handlePrint = () => {
    // is getElementById an anti pattern even if I'm not modyfying the DOM?
    const node = document.getElementById("print-file");
    node.contentWindow.focus();
    node.contentWindow.print();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2>PDF Viewer Component</h2>
        <object data={pdfFile} type="application/pdf">
          <iframe
            title="pdf document"
            id="print-file"
            src={`https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${pdfFile}&embedded=true`}
          />
        </object>
        <button onClick={this.handlePrint}>Print</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong inside `handlePrint()`?

I have a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v987w15zw) where you can see the error in details when firing `handlePrint()`

Comment: One thing I notice in your sandbox is that clicking on your `Print` button raise an cross-origin issue.  Maybe try it with a local pdf and see if it behaves differently. "Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown..."

Answer (score 6):

You cannot print an iframe or window from another domain, how @Trevor Reid says, you should define in your frontend crossdomain policies, and also in the server.

To offer you some solution, you can open a popup loading the PDF and the navigator usually or open the pdf where you can download, or directly download the file.

The code I can propose is the next one:

```
handlePrint = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open(pdfFile, "PRINT", "height=400,width=600");
};
```

Also, a bit more difficult to implement is use the following library:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/pdf_print_service.js

I hope this helps to you

Comment: This should probably help. : )

Comment: This will open in a new tab and open the pdf file and print, is there a way to print in a same tab without opening pdf?